# How to take dictionary and return a table with a row for each

Tags: sql

I have a table like this, status_change is a dictionary, it has multiple status,
[image]

How can i return a table: the dictionary key becomes the column header
[image]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: which db platform are you using?

Comment: the row 1 does not have END element.
but you can use OPENJSON to read json object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Are you using another language to script this, or do you need a solution in pure SQL

Answer (score 0):

this is an example to read json to table and pivot to able to add to temp table

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(500) = '{"Not Started":"2022-02-25","Started":"2022-02-22","End":"2022-02-24"}'
--SET @json = '{"Not Started":"2022-02-25","Started":"2022-02-22"}'

SELECT resTable.[End],
       resTable.[Started],
       resTable.[Not Started] 
FROM
(SELECT [Key] AS col, Value AS val FROM OPENJSON(@json)) AS j
PIVOT(
    MAX(j.val)
    FOR col IN ([Not Started], [Started], [End])
) AS resTable
```

[image]